# Different behaviors between find -exec and piping through xargs

Tags: bash, find, chmod, xargs, recursive

I wanted to recursively run `chmod go+w` in a particular folder including hidden files, and I first tried

```
find . -name ".*" -o -name "*" -exec chmod go+w {} \;
```

but I found that it wasn't affecting hidden files. To check myself, I ran just

```
find . -name ".*" -o -name "*"
```

and the hidden files were listed. I also noticed that if I excluded the `-o -name "*"` part it would chmod the hidden files (but exclude non-hidden of course). My last attempt was to use xargs instead

```
find . -name ".*" -o -name "*" | xargs chmod go+w
```

which finally worked as expected. What am I doing wrong in the first snippet?

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)
>
> GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

Comment: Apart from `find` , `chmod` with `-R, --recursive` could also be used right, like `chmod -R go+w <dir>` ?

Comment: As someone put it, the key to understanding `find` is to understand that it doesn't find files, it evaluates expressions. It also doesn't really have distinct concepts of "tests" and "actions", they are all operations on the same level.

Comment: `find` locates and reports dot-files by default...

Comment: Not in my experience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to bind the two name tests together with parens.

To illustrate this, let's consider a directory with three regular files:

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  .hidden1  .hidden2  not_hidden
```

Now, let's the original command:

```
$ find . -name ".*" -o -name "*" -exec echo Found {} \;
Found ./not_hidden
```

Only the non-hidden file is found.

Next, let's add parens to group the two name tests together:

```
$ find . \( -name ".*" -o -name "*" \) -exec echo Found {} \;
Found .
Found ./not_hidden
Found ./.hidden1
Found ./.hidden2
```

All files are found.

The solution is to use parens.

#### More details

In the original command, there is not operator between `-name "*"` and  `-exec ... \;`.  Consequently, `find` assumes the default operator which is logical-and.  Because logical-and binds tighter than logical-or (`-o`), this means that the command is interpreted as:

```
find . \( -name ".*" \) -o \( -name "*" -exec echo Found {} \; \)
```

This means that the `exec` is run only if the first `name` condition failed to match.

For more information, see the *OPERATORS* section in `man find`.

#### What happens without `-exec`

Let's try using a simple `-print`:

```
$ find . -name ".*" -o -name "*" -print
./not_hidden
```

As you can see, `-print` bound to the `-name "*"` with the implicit logical-and as above.

But, consider what happens without any action specified:

```
$ find . -name ".*" -o -name "*"
.
./not_hidden
./.hidden1
./.hidden2
```

Here, all files were found.  The reason is that, in this version, `-o` is the *only* operator.